# how to connect to on-premise active directory from cloud-service in azure

Tags: active-directory, vpn, azure-cloud-services

**Problem**
we are planning to connect to our on-premise resource (such as active directory) from a third-party application which is hosted on Azure Cloud-Service, without exposing the LDAP path to public network.

Setting up a VPN connection is not an option for now, due to security reasons, we are looking to see if there is any alternative solutions available other than setting up VPN connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can use Azure BizTalk Service, to setup a secure connection to your on-premise resources, including SQL Server, Active Directory and etc.

This way will have several benefits as once the connection is set, you can code like you are connecting to an on-premise resource, but it is a bit expensive to use.

More Info :

1. **[MSDN: BizTalk Services](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/biztalk-services/)**
2. **[Introduction to Azure BizTalk Hybrid Connection on](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kEgNE_-KC90)**

Note : unfortunately Azure biztalk is not available for azure cloud-services for now, and it's only available for Azure WebSite and Azure Mobile Services, However you can use it with a proper architecture, to access it from your cloud-service.